# get all files related to git push

Tags: git, githooks

is there a way to get ( perhaps with a server side hook ) all the files related to a push ? like :

when a user does : `$`git push origin master

if we use $git log  then, somehow the hook has to have the SHA-1 in order to get the files related to the push ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, this is generally do in [a pre-receive or post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) (depending if you want to allow the push or just post-process it).
Both hooks take a list of references that are being pushed from stdin.

See for instance [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hartfordfive/9670011):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "### Attempting to validate puppet files... ####"

# See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#pre-receive    
oldrev=$1
newrev=$2
refname=$3

while read oldrev newrev refname; do

    # Get the file names, without directory, of the files that have been modified
    # between the new revision and the old revision
    files=`git diff --name-only ${oldrev} ${newrev}`

    # Get a list of all objects in the new revision
    objects=`git ls-tree --full-name -r ${newrev}`

    # Iterate over each of these files
    for file in ${files}; do

        # Search for the file name in the list of all objects
        object=`echo -e "${objects}" | egrep "(\s)${file}\$" | awk '{ print $3 }'`

        # If it's not present, then continue to the the next itteration
        if [ -z ${object} ]; then 
            continue; 
        fi
        ...
```

In the example above, it not only get the list (commit after commit) pushed, but also their content (with `git ls-tree ...|grep file`)